# ET.iterparse is not loading all XML tags inside a specifc tag in python with xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree, large-data

**My code:**

```
tree = ET.iterparse(file_path, events=('start',))
    for _, elem in tree:
        if 'product' in elem.tag:
            if elem.attrib.get('product-id') == "B4_1003847_000":
                print(ET.tostring(elem))
                breakpoint()
            process_product(elem)
```

**XML Tag copied from XML file which is basically a child of the root tag.**

```
<product product-id="B4_1003847_000">
    <ean/>
    <upc/>
    <unit/>
    <min-order-quantity>1</min-order-quantity>
    <step-quantity>1</step-quantity>
    <display-name xml:lang="x-default">Pink piggy bank     </display-name>
    <short-description xml:lang="x-default">&lt;p&gt;Ceramic piggy bank measuring 13 x 9 x 9 cm. without a hole in the bottom, but includes a hammer.&lt;/p&gt;
    </short-description>
    <store-force-price-flag>false</store-force-price-flag>
    <store-non-inventory-flag>false</store-non-inventory-flag>
    <store-non-revenue-flag>false</store-non-revenue-flag>
    <store-non-discountable-flag>false</store-non-discountable-flag>
    <online-flag>false</online-flag>
    <online-flag site-id="FlyingTiger_UAE">true</online-flag>
    <available-flag>true</available-flag>
    <searchable-flag>true</searchable-flag>
    <images>
        <image-group view-type="large">
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__01?$prd_large$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__02?$prd_large$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__03?$prd_large$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__04?$prd_large$"/>
        </image-group>
        <image-group variation-value="B401_000" view-type="large">
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__01?$prd_large$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__02?$prd_large$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__03?$prd_large$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__04?$prd_large$"/>
        </image-group>
        <image-group view-type="medium">
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__01?$prd_medium$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__02?$prd_medium$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__03?$prd_medium$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__04?$prd_medium$"/>
        </image-group>
        <image-group variation-value="B401_000" view-type="medium">
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__01?$prd_medium$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__02?$prd_medium$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__03?$prd_medium$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__04?$prd_medium$"/>
        </image-group>
        <image-group view-type="mobile">
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__01?$prd_mobile$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__02?$prd_mobile$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__03?$prd_mobile$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__04?$prd_mobile$"/>
        </image-group>
        <image-group variation-value="B401_000" view-type="mobile">
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__01?$prd_mobile$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__02?$prd_mobile$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__03?$prd_mobile$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__04?$prd_mobile$"/>
        </image-group>
        <image-group view-type="thumbnail">
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__01?$prd_thumbnail$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__02?$prd_thumbnail$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__03?$prd_thumbnail$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__04?$prd_thumbnail$"/>
        </image-group>
        <image-group variation-value="B401_000" view-type="thumbnail">
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__01?$prd_thumbnail$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__02?$prd_thumbnail$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__03?$prd_thumbnail$"/>
            <image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__04?$prd_thumbnail$"/>
        </image-group>
    </images>
    <tax-class-id>standard</tax-class-id>
    <brand>FLYING TIGER </brand>
    <manufacturer-name>FLYING TIGER </manufacturer-name>
    <sitemap-included-flag>true</sitemap-included-flag>
    <sitemap-changefrequency>daily</sitemap-changefrequency>
    <sitemap-priority>1.0</sitemap-priority>
    <page-attributes/>
    <custom-attributes>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="brandCategoryId">B4</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="buyingCategory">B401010</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="color">B401_000</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="defaultName">Pink piggy bank</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="defaultSizeGrid">Standard</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="geoAllowedShippingCountries">
            <value>ALL</value>
        </custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="internalProductName">PIG BANK WITH HAMMER</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="isItemBulky">false</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="isItemPrepaid">false</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="isReturnable">true</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="isReturnable" site-id="FlyingTiger_UAE">true</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="season">000</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="seasonDescription">Non Seasonable Items</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="size">B401022_000</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="sizeRefinement" xml:lang="x-default">B401022_000</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="subBrand" xml:lang="x-default">Flying Tiger</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="subSeason">000</custom-attribute>
        <custom-attribute attribute-id="subSeasonDescription">Non Seasonable Items</custom-attribute>
    </custom-attributes>
    <variations>
        <attributes>
            <variation-attribute attribute-id="color" variation-attribute-id="color">
                <display-name xml:lang="x-default">color</display-name>
                <variation-attribute-values>
                    <variation-attribute-value value="B401_000">
                        <display-value xml:lang="x-default">B401_000</display-value>
                    </variation-attribute-value>
                </variation-attribute-values>
            </variation-attribute>
            <variation-attribute attribute-id="size" variation-attribute-id="size">
                <display-name xml:lang="x-default">size</display-name>
                <variation-attribute-values>
                    <variation-attribute-value value="000">
                        <display-value xml:lang="x-default">No Size</display-value>
                    </variation-attribute-value>
                </variation-attribute-values>
            </variation-attribute>
        </attributes>
        <variants>
            <variant product-id="B4_1003847_000-000"/>
        </variants>
    </variations>
    <classification-category catalog-id="siteCatalog_FlyingTiger_UAE">gifts-giftsforkids</classification-category>
    <pinterest-enabled-flag>true</pinterest-enabled-flag>
    <facebook-enabled-flag>true</facebook-enabled-flag>
    <store-attributes>
        <force-price-flag>false</force-price-flag>
        <non-inventory-flag>false</non-inventory-flag>
        <non-revenue-flag>false</non-revenue-flag>
        <non-discountable-flag>false</non-discountable-flag>
    </store-attributes>
</product>
```

**The same tag return by `print(ET.tostring(elem))`**

```
<ns0:product xmlns:ns0="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/catalog/2006-10-31" product-id="B4_1003847_000">
        <ns0:ean />
        <ns0:upc />
        <ns0:unit />
        <ns0:min-order-quantity>1</ns0:min-order-quantity>
        <ns0:step-quantity>1</ns0:step-quantity>
        <ns0:display-name xml:lang="x-default">Pink piggy bank     </ns0:display-name>
        <ns0:short-description xml:lang="x-default">&lt;p&gt;Ceramic piggy bank measuring 13 x 9 x 9 cm. without a hole in the bottom, but includes a hammer.&lt;/p&gt;
        </ns0:short-description>
        <ns0:store-force-price-flag>false</ns0:store-force-price-flag>
        <ns0:store-non-inventory-flag>false</ns0:store-non-inventory-flag>
        <ns0:store-non-revenue-flag>false</ns0:store-non-revenue-flag>
        <ns0:store-non-discountable-flag>false</ns0:store-non-discountable-flag>
        <ns0:online-flag>false</ns0:online-flag>
        <ns0:online-flag site-id="FlyingTiger_UAE">true</ns0:online-flag>
        <ns0:available-flag>true</ns0:available-flag>
        <ns0:searchable-flag>true</ns0:searchable-flag>
        <ns0:images>
            <ns0:image-group view-type="large">
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__01?$prd_large$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__02?$prd_large$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__03?$prd_large$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__04?$prd_large$" />
            </ns0:image-group>
            <ns0:image-group variation-value="B401_000" view-type="large">
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__01?$prd_large$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__02?$prd_large$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__03?$prd_large$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__04?$prd_large$" />
            </ns0:image-group>
            <ns0:image-group view-type="medium">
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__01?$prd_medium$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__02?$prd_medium$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__03?$prd_medium$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__04?$prd_medium$" />
            </ns0:image-group>
            <ns0:image-group variation-value="B401_000" view-type="medium">
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__01?$prd_medium$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__02?$prd_medium$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__03?$prd_medium$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__04?$prd_medium$" />
            </ns0:image-group>
            <ns0:image-group view-type="mobile">
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__01?$prd_mobile$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__02?$prd_mobile$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__03?$prd_mobile$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__04?$prd_mobile$" />
            </ns0:image-group>
            <ns0:image-group variation-value="B401_000" view-type="mobile">
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__01?$prd_mobile$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__02?$prd_mobile$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__03?$prd_mobile$" />
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__04?$prd_mobile$" />
            </ns0:image-group>
            <ns0:image-group view-type="thumbnail">
                <ns0:image path="B4_1003847_000__B401_000__101__01?$prd_thumbnail$" /></ns0:image-group></ns0:images></ns0:product>
```

The noticing point is that in the code printed XML is missing all the tags after `<images>`. I tried breakpoint() to debug it but didn't work.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the complete contents before the end event for the element.

Comment: `iterparse()` knows also the events (**"start-ns"**, "start", **"end-ns"** , "end",  .. and others to work with `namespaces` in XML, find more [info](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) and [example](http://pythonic.zoomquiet.top/data/20061029121016/index.html). You will find the namespaces declaration into the **<root>** - element.

Comment: Yes, the end was the ideal option. it worked.